# Create a Pandas table via string matching

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have a 3 column table where two columns are URLs and 1 column is a string that might be contained in the urls. The first 100,000 rows can be found at this link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Slusks/LeagueDataAnalysis/main/short_urls.csv

In theory, values in eurl and surl should be the same, and for every value of each, there should be a gameid that matches both, ie:

```
https://datapoint/Identity1/foobar.com | Identity1 | https://datapoint/Identity1/foobar.com
```

I've tried some SQL queries on the data and cant get them to line up

```
SELECT
   *
from
   table
where
   eurl = surl;
```

since the values started out in different tables, I also tried joining on table1.url = table2.url and that hasn't worked either. It just shows up blank:

```
SELECT 
    s.url, e.gameid
FROM
    elixerdata e
        JOIN
    scrapeddata s ON e.url = s.url;
```

I'm trying to get the gameID's to match up to the surl column and using the eurl column as validation to confirm that it worked correctly.I'm probably not providing enough code or steps to get good feedback but I figure I might as well ask since I am low on ideas myself.

EDIT1:
I cleaned the quotes off by loading the table into python and then re-writing it to a csv with pandas. The data in the csv appears to not have any quotes, then I load it into SQL with the following:

```
drop table if exists urltable;
create table urltable(
eurl varchar(255),
gameid varchar(20),
surl varchar(255));

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'csvfile.csv' into table urltable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

When I read the table in MySQL Workbench there are no quotes, but if I export that table back to a csv, all the quotes are back, only for the surl column though.

Comment: your csv is badly formed with weird quotes, clean it and your first query works.

Comment: That formatting seems to appear only after I export a table from mySQL and only for that column. Is there some sort of metadata that gets pulled into mySQL that's persisting across programs?